# How to detect when DOM ready after ngFor?

Tags: angular

I want to animate `<li>` elements (e.g. usign jQuery).

But how can I detect when DOM is done after ***ngFor**?

*View*

```html
<ul #ul>
  <li *ngFor="let event of events">{{event|date:'medium'}}</li>
</ul>

<button (click)="showEvents()">Show events</button>
```

*Component*

```js
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('ul') ulRef: ElementRef;

  events: any[];

  showEvents(): void {

    // Assume this set of events will be different in every button click
    this.events = [
      new Date(2017, 1),
      new Date(2017, 3),
      new Date(2019, 6)
    ];

    const li = this.ulRef.nativeElement.children;

    // This logs empty array for first time or 
    // previous set of children for next times
    console.log( li );
  };

}
```

**P.S.** I know using `setTimeout` will solve this, but is it right approach?

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @ThinkingMedia. Using template variable on the `<li>` and `QueryList` I can watch for changes.

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let event of events" #li>{{event|date:'medium'}}</li>
</ul>
```

```js
  @ViewChildren('li') li: QueryList<ElementRef>; 

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.li.changes.subscribe(() => {
      const elements = this.li.toArray().map(i => i.nativeElement);
      // Here I can have access to the li elements when DOM updated
      console.log(elements);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Try using a template `#name` on the `<li #name>` tags and watch for changes using `@ViewChildren('#name')` using the observable.

Answer (score 8):

you can use the **AfterViewInit** life-cycle hook.

this life-cycle hook is trigger after the view is initialized.

you can use it in this way:

```
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{

  @ViewChild('ul') ulRef: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // your logic
  }

  events: any[];

  showEvents(): void {

    this.events = [
      new Date(2017, 1),
      new Date(2017, 3),
      new Date(2019, 6)
    ];

    const li = this.ulRef.nativeElement.children;

    // This logs empty arrays since DOM not changed yet
    console.log( li );
  };

}
```

Comment: But `ngAfterViewInit` called only once. What if user several times press show events button with difference set of events?

Comment: @taras-d, use `ngAfterViewChecked` then