# ngFor keeps in DOM elements for old items after ngAfterViewChecked

Tags: angular

I'm using now Angular 10. I have two components, mySection and myGroup. The myGroup can contain some mySections. I populate mySection using ngFor based on an array of items. In myGroup I use the hook ngAfterViewChecked. When I change the items in myList and try to count myGroup elements in ngAfterViewChecked I get a collection that contains old and new elements.

```
<my-group>
  <my-section *ngFor="let item of list">
    {{item.name}}
  </my-section>
  <my-section *ngIf="!list>
    no items found
  </my-section>
</my group>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-group',
  ...
})
export class MyGroup implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {

  @ViewChild('self', {static: true}) group: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    console.log(this.group.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('my-section'));
  }

  ...
}
```

For example the list contained 10 elements. User interaction changed it to another 6 elements, completely different. In ngAfterViewChecked I get a collection with 16 elements. Afterall displayed are only my-section for the 6 new items. So the DOM must be manipulated by Angular also after this hook.

**Is there another, better hook where I get the DOM completely updated after the list of ngFor changes ??**

And sorry for syntactic errors, I simplified it from more complex code.

Comment: What is ‘self’...?

Comment: "@ViewChild('self'" should create reference to entire component content. Actually this part also works.

Comment: Ran into the same issue. See here for one possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45633642/how-to-detect-when-dom-ready-after-ngfor. I'd like to know why Angular does this, however.